# 3D space game development

Tags: java, game-engine, multiplayer, 3d-engine

I want to develop a 3D game (sci-fi type with spaceships) which can be played on multiplayer mode and by multiplayer i mean around 10 players for start as it will be a personal testing project and mostly educational.
I have been searching for some days about the available languages and engines but i am kinda confused.
Since i have been learning Java for my 1st year in I.T university and i have pretty good understanding i thought i would go with the Java language and develop that game on an applet so it could be played on a browser.
After going through an applet game tutorial i understood how graphics work on an applet.

So.. 1st question: Could an applet carry the burden of a 3D game especially on multiplayer?
My thinking: It's a space game so the graphics should not be such a big problem since it wont be that crowded with entities apart from ships, planets and some effects.

If the java applet is not the way for my project i would't mind "developing it on desktop"(i mean not making it a browser game).
2nd question: Should i use Unity engine for my purpose(space game)? If not name other language/engine combo.

Comment: The second question is not really a question, as it will invite opinions rather than facts. I disagree with those voting to close though, as the first question seems legitimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the fact that you're asking this question is a big red flag. Have you written a Pong clone? A Pac-Man clone? A Wolfenstein clone? Game programming is nontrivial. And you want to make it multiplayer and in 3D (which makes it about 300x more complicated). Also, this question should be on [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Oh by the way, you can't run network applications in Applets (unless you do funky stuff with the permissions), so a [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html) application is preferred. But to answer your question, um, yeah... sure.

Comment: I totally agree, Pong, Space Invaders, or any other classic game is a must for a start!

Comment: I see what you mean. I will start making the "small games" to get used to.
Now about the applet. As long as i have a server which hosts both the web app and the game won't it work? Take a look at this:[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)